# EventSourceHQ send event returns OK, but does nothing

Tags: ruby, heroku, server-sent-events

I'm using EventSourceHQ with Heroku. I'm not using an existing client, but re-writing the client in Scala. It's pretty simple, as the [Ruby](https://github.com/eshq/eshq-gem/blob/master/lib/eshq.rb) [implementation](https://github.com/eshq/eshq-gem/blob/master/lib/eshq/client.rb) shows.

Creating a socket is successful and the client-side javascript seems happy with the resulting socket_id. But when I trigger an event on the server `eventsourcehq.com/event` returns `HTTP 200` with the body being `{ }`. Furthermore no event handlers are executed in the browser. That is, the server sends an event to eventsourcehq.com but that event is not forwarded to the client in the browser.

The meat of how I post to eventsourcehq in the server (using dispatch) is:

```
val (key, secret, serviceURL) = 
  (properties("ESHQ_KEY"), properties("ESHQ_SECRET"), properties("ESHQ_URL"))

def createSocket(channel: String) = post("/socket", Map("channel" -> channel))

def publish(data: String, channel: String) = post("/event", 
  Map("channel" -> channel, "data" -> data))

private def post(path: String, params: Map[String, String]): ActionResult = {
  val request = url(s"$serviceURL$path") << params << credentials
  Await.result(Http(request).either, 5.seconds).fold(
    {t => InternalServerError(s"Failed to post $request: ${t.getMessage}")},
    {r => Ok(r.getResponseBody)}
  )
}

private def credentials = {
  val time = (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000).toString
  Map("key" -> key, "timestamp" -> time, "token" -> token(key, secret, time))
}

private def token(strings: String*) = {
  val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
  md.digest(strings.mkString(":").getBytes("UTF-8")).map("%02x".format(_)).mkString
}
```

As in the Ruby client, both the `createSocket` (`open`) and `publish` (`send`) methods delegate to the same http posting logic.

On the client:

```
var serverEvents = (function () {

    var eshq = new ESHQ("forkpin");

    // callback called when the connection is made
    eshq.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Open event", e);
    };

    // called when a new message with no specific type has been received
    eshq.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log("Message type: %s, message data: %s", e.type, e.data);
    };

    // callback called on error
    eshq.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Error event", e);
    };

    return eshq;

})();
```

Where might I be going wrong? How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged this further with wireshark. I found the event being published, but with the message as the channel name and the channel name as the message. I had mixed around my params.

One year of no pastries for me.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks right on the server-side as far as I can see. Can you share the JavaScript code you use to bind to the ESHQ events?

Also, if you're planning on open-sourcing this Scala-client I would be happy to set it up on the eshq Github org and give you commit accesss.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. I'm aware that you need more reputation for that...

Comment: Yeah, hopefully I can turn it into a good answer once I have some information on the client-side code :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. JS added. If this comes down to a lack of js chops I'm going to deny myself a pastry.